# Enable XA transactions for MSSQL Server docker image

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2016

I have MSSQL Server Linux docker image that I use for development and I need to enable XA transactions on this instance, I search a lot but all the tutorials I found show only how to do that from a windows machine, no Linux.

So How to enable XA transactions from command line, or is there a configuration file for that.

Comment: XA transactions appears to rely on the distributed transaction coordinator service (MSDTC). This is a Windows service independent of SQL Server. I can't find any authoritative documentation, but I doubt MSDTC is available as a Linux daemon in preview 1 (and might never be). You'll almost certainly need to run SQL Server inside a Windows VM (rather than Docker) to use XA transactions.

Comment: Thanks Ed, appreciate your Help. I did use a VM in the end.

Comment: It has finally been added and everything should work in Ubuntu 18.04. I'm not sure how to find those images, though. Ref: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/4042

Comment: For anyone coming to this comment: They can be found at https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server

Answer (score 7):

In SQLServer 2016 and 2017 for Linux it is not possible to use XA transactions. Starting with SqlServer 2019 for Linux (In preview at the time of writing), [distributed transaction support has been added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-msdtc-docker?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
docker run \
   -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>' \
   -e 'MSSQL_RPC_PORT=135' -e 'MSSQL_DTC_TCP_PORT=51000' \
   -p 51433:1433 -p 135:135 -p 51000:51000  \
   -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CTP2.3-ubuntu
```

You should then be able to [enable the JDBC XA support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-xa-transactions?view=sql-server-ver15) with:

```
EXEC sp_sqljdbc_xa_install
```

The user needs to have the permissions:

```
 use master;
 sp_grantdbaccess 'myuser', 'myuser';
 EXEC sp_addrolemember [SqlJDBCXAUser], 'myuser'
```

Comment: Very good addition to the otherwise difficult to understand article linked above. Helped me a lot. Perhaps for the layman like me: it took me a while to figure out that the docker port mapping for the server is 51433 rather than the standard 1433 used in your connection, also that you need to log into the server with a client like dbeaver to run the scripts.

Comment: If I want to enable XA on my database and the user is defined against my database, how do I add that user to this role? I tried with `sa` user but even `sa` doesn't seem to be available on `master` and nor does my username on my database. Can you please shed some light on this? Thanks