# enable xa datasource for mssql server on linux docker image

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, sql-server-2017, xa

I'm using the MSQL 2017 docker image on my local linux environment that I'm using for development. I need to enable the XA datasource feature but I cannot find a solution to do this. Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: MSDTC is not available on the linux docker container right now:  https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/28

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable XA transactions for MSSQL Server docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900016/enable-xa-transactions-for-mssql-server-docker-image)