# SQLServer hung on Using 'xplog70.dll' version 'xxx' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_msver'

Tags: java, sql-server, docker, jdbc

System Information:
OS: `macOS Catalina 10.15.2` and `Windows 10`

Docker Image: `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU2-ubuntu-16.04`(2019 GA has same issue)

JDBC Driver: `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.2.1.jre8`

Context: 
Running database in docker container and accessing via JDBC driver.
I start the docker container using https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/ api

Behavior: 
Startup of database goes fine and I get:

```
[01/24/2020 14:53:23:405 CST] 051 SQLServerContainer             output                         I 
2020-01-24 20:53:23.41 spid12s     Clearing tempdb database.
```

I then execute an init-sqlserver.sql file to enable jdbc xa connection:

```sql
-- Create database
CREATE DATABASE TEST;

-- Enable XA connections
EXEC sp_sqljdbc_xa_install;
```

and I get

```
...
[01/24/2020 14:53:23:969 CST] 051 SQLServerContainer             output                         I 
2020-01-24 20:53:23.97 spid52      Starting up database 'TEST'.
...
[01/24/2020 14:53:24:377 CST] 001 ScriptUtils                    executeDatabaseScript          I Executed database script from resources/init-sqlserver.sql in 855 ms.
[01/24/2020 14:53:25:029 CST] 051 SQLServerContainer             output                         I 
2020-01-24 20:53:25.04 spid25s     The tempdb database has 6 data file(s).
```

When I actually try to use an xa connection I get:

```
[01/24/2020 14:53:47:496 CST] 051 SQLServerContainer             output                         I 
2020-01-24 20:53:47.49 spid53      Initializing Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) resource manager [820e1ea9-c921-4350-897e-a7534d9d1ed7] for server instance 8b0aca425794. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
[01/24/2020 14:53:47:504 CST] 051 SQLServerContainer             output                         I 
2020-01-24 20:53:47.50 spid53      Recovery of any in-doubt distributed transactions involving Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has completed. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
[01/24/2020 14:59:44:692 CST] 051 SQLServerContainer             output                         I 
2020-01-24 20:59:44.71 spid62      Attempting to load library 'xplog70.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
[01/24/2020 14:59:44:742 CST] 051 SQLServerContainer             output                         I 
2020-01-24 20:59:44.76 spid62      Using 'xplog70.dll' version '2019.150.4003' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_msver'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

And I hang on the last part indefinitely.  You can also see there is an approx 6 minute hang between two of the steps.

What I am trying to accomplish in my source code:

```java
    /**
     * Enlist a two-phase capable resource in a global transaction.
     */
    public void getXAConnection() throws Exception {
        setUpTables(ds1); 

        tran.begin();
        try (Connection con1 = ds1.getConnection()) {
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con1.prepareStatement("insert into cities values (?, ?, ?)");
            pstmt.setString(1, "Wanamingo");
            pstmt.setInt(2, 1086);
            pstmt.setString(3, "Goodhue");
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();

            tran.commit();
        } catch (Throwable x) {
            try {
                tran.rollback();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
            throw x;
        }
    }
```

Questions:

1. Shouldn't the initialization of MSDTC happen during the execution of
   `EXEC sp_sqljdbc_xa_install;` stored procedure?
2. Why is there such a long delay between stored procedures?
3. Why do we hang on the last stored procedure?
4. Is this an issue with the docker image or the JDBC driver? (This worked on derby, db2, postgres, and oracle)

Comment: Note: I have also opened an issue against the docker container to help resolve this as well: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/554

Comment: Can you explain the setup a bit more, are you running the Linux version of SQL on the 2019-CU2-ubuntu-16.04? Where does the Windows 10 come into?

Comment: I am running the Linux version of SQL Server in a docker environment.  I have tested this on both a Mac and Windows machine to see if this issue happened on both machines.  it did.

Comment: Ok, can you confirm for me that you're following the instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-msdtc-docker?view=sql-server-ver15 - and can you update to [CU3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes-2019?view=sql-server-ver15#cu2). This old Q&A seems to match the problem you're facing, and says this issue should be resolved in 2019: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40900016/495455

Comment: Yup that is the guide I followed to set this up.  And I tried CU3 and the problem still persists.

Comment: You might actually want to contact MSFT support on this one, if you work where you do they will have support credits with their MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server may have one or more of the extended stored procedures disabled by default for security reasons.

If this is a non-production development environment, have you tried connecting to the SQL Server with an SQL Server administrator account?